# Replacing one fragment with another

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have seen similar problem to this posted here but have been unable to figure out what I have been doing wrong:

So I have a listFragment and a detailsFragment. When the button in the listFragment is pressed I want it to display the detailsFragment.

This is my layout xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal" >

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/listContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/detailsContainer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:visibility="gone"/>
```

This is my FragmentTransaction code:

```
 public void onRssItemSelected(String link) {
    Boolean dual_pane = getResources().getBoolean(R.bool.dual_pane);
    if (dual_pane==true) {
        DetailFragment fragment = (DetailFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.detailFragment);
        fragment.setText(link);
    } else {
        DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();

        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
        fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listContainer, fragment);
        fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
        fragmentTransaction.commit();

        fragment.setText(link);
    }
}
```

The Landscape version works fine, but the portrait keeps crashing. As I said I have looked at a lot of similar questions but don't see what I am doing wrong.
I also tried using replace(R.id.detailsContainer, fragment) to no avail.

Thanks a lot!

Comment: You need to post the stack trace of the crash.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like this line is causing issue:

> fragment.setText(link);

because your fragment has not yet finished creating/drawing.

Try removing mentioned line from `else` statement and add this to your code:

```
... 
} else {
    DetailFragment fragment = new DetailFragment();
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("LINK", link);
    fragment.setArguments(bundle);
...
```

and then in your fragment's `onCreateView()`
call:

```
 if (getArguments() != null) {
    setText(getArguments().getString("LINK"));
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
bundle.putString("key", link);
fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.listContainer, fragment);
fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
fragmentTransaction.commit();
```